# Is there any differences between $var and ${var}

Tags: php

Are these 2 two "spellings" equivalent? Just wondering.

Answer (score 6):

`${var}` out of context could be either correct or not. If it is used inside of the string like `"foo ${var} bar"` - then it is the same.

If it is used right in the code - then `${var}` is incorrect, and `${'var'}` should be used instead.

The valid cases for using `${...}` are:

1. Inside the string in cases like `"ab${cd}e"` - when all the letters go without spaces, `"${a['b']}"` - when you use it with arrays
2. When you want to assemble the variable name dynamically: `${'a_' . $i}`

Comment: @Mihai Stancu: yep, that's what I have been adding additionally ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much. The only difference is that you can enter code to be parsed in between the curly braces to get "variable" variable names.

Ex.

```
${'t'.'e'.'s'.'t'} = 'test'; // is the same as $test = 'test';  
${substr('testaaa',0,4)} = 'test'; // the same
```

You can even do something like:

```
${ 'a' == 'b' ? 'Foo' : 'test' } = 'test'; //the same
```

It is essentially the same as:

```
$var_name = substr('testaaa',0,4);
$$var_name = 'test';
```

Comment: Important note: "you can enter code to be parsed in between the curly braces to get "variable" variable names" --- it is not 100% correct. The code should be an **expression**. You cannot just put some arbitrary code there